# Replacing text between two specific strings

Tags: centos, text-processing, replace

I have large number of files that have an deprecated css value "hspace" and I want to change it with other css style value. Here is an example:
we have:

```
hspace='5'
```

and we want to change with:

```
style="margin: 0 5px;"
```

each file has different value inside `hspace`, one can be  `hspace='5'` other `hspace='2'`, `hspace='7'` and so on.

what I want is find in all files in specific directory:

```
hspace='ANY NUMBER'
```

and replace with:

```
style="margin: 0 5px;"
```

Any suggestion to do this in bash centos os?

Comment: `hspice='8'` => will be transformed into what?

Comment: with style="margin: 0 8px;"

Comment: Then you need to edit your main theme where you are stating that: hspace='ANY NUMBER' to replace with: style="margin: 0 5px;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this command for replacing (assuming GNU `sed` as found on CentOS):

```
sed -i "s/hspace='\([0-9]*\)'/style=\"margin: 0 \1px;\"/g" filename.html
```

To replace in all .html-files:

```
find . -type f -name '*.html' -exec sed -i "s/hspace='\([0-9]*\)'/style=\"margin: 0 \1px;\"/g" {} +
```

Comment: in my case files don't have extension. I tried to use `'*'` instead of `'*.html'` but doesn't work

Comment: ok, seems that @Stéphane-Chazelas changed last solution and now it works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i should have checked it before publishing. Thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas for edits.